# Pass Model to Controller to Change in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my situation, I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputModel" />
<div class="button-container">
    <button type="button" ng-click="setValue(inputModel)"></button>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="inputModelTwo" />
<div class="button-container">
    <button type="button" ng-click="setValue(inputModelTwo)"></button>
</div>
```

And my view controller:

```
$scope.setValue = function (valueToSet) {
    valueToSet = "Some value.";
};
```

I need to be able to "connect" the input fields and their buttons and I'm doing this by having the respective button pass the respective input field's model to the controller to be modified. The problem is that when I click the button the function fires off and `valueToSet` is changed but the change isn't reflected back in the view! What am I missing?

Comment: your `setValue` method currently isn't doing anything but reassigning the value of the passed argument?

Comment: You don't pass the model, you just pass the value of your model. It's a primitive _String_. And in your function `$scope.setValue` variable valueToSet is a _String_. Also, you can access your models `inputModel` and `inputModelTwo` in your `$scope` like `$scope.inputModel` and `$scope.inputModelTwo`. All depends on what you want to do, so please clairify your question

Comment: @ababashka You are right, the problem was I was just passing the primitive string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to dynamically pass in your models as a function parameter, you'll need to access a **PROPERTY** on the models by using dot notation.

Try defining the models in the controller like so:

```
$scope.inputModel = {};
$scope.inputModelTwo = {};

$scope.inputModel.text = 'hey';
$scope.inputModelTwo.text = 'ho';
```

Then pass in the entire model to the function as you were already doing.

Inside the function, alter the property that you desire (in this case 'text'), like so:

```
$scope.setValue = function (valueToSet) {
    console.log(valueToSet);
   valueToSet.text = "Some value.";
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/qgzv2ux7/)